# Replacing element in list without list comprehension, slicing or using [ ]s

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension

[I'm taking this online Python course](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/14-methods/) and they do not like the students using one-line solutions. The course will not accept brackets for this solution.

I already solved the problem using list comprehension, but the course rejected my answer.

The problem reads:

> Using `index` and other list methods, write a function `replace(list, X, Y)` which replaces all occurrences of `X` in `list` with `Y`. For example, if `L = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]` then `replace(L, 1, 7)` would change the contents of `L` to `[3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 9]`. To make this exercise a challenge, you are not allowed to use `[]`.
>
> Note: you don't need to use return.

This is what I have so far, but it breaks because of TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

```
list = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

def replace(list, X, Y):
   while X in list:
      for i,v in range(len(list)):
         if v==1:
            list.remove(1)
            list.insert(i, 7)

replace(list, 1, 7)
```

This was my original answer, but it was rejected.

```
list = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]

def replace(list, X, Y):
   print([Y if v == X else v for v in list])

replace(list, 1, 7)
```

Any ideas on how to fix my longer solution?

Comment: Your solution is wrong, it should be: `print([Y if v == X else v for v in list])`.

Comment: Try `for i, v in enumerate(list):`.

Comment: @Serdalis. You're right. The course still won't accept that answer.

Comment: @Serdalis The solution is incorrect also because it does not modify the list passed to it, which is a requirement.

Comment: @Sven Marnach. We're not allowed to use enumerate. Isn't it the same as in range(len(list))?

Comment: @StacyM No, that returns just returns all the numbers from 0 to the length of the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`range()` returns a flat list of integers, so you can't unpack it into two arguments. Use `enumerate` to get index and value tuples:

```
def replace(l, X, Y):
  for i,v in enumerate(l):
     if v == X:
        l.pop(i)
        l.insert(i, Y)

l = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
replace(l, 1, 7)
```

If you're not allowed to use `enumerate`, use a plain old counter:

```
def replace(l, X, Y):
  i = 0
  for v in l:
     if v == X:
        l.pop(i)
        l.insert(i, Y)
     i += 1

l = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
replace(list, 1, 7)
```

Finally, you could use what the authors of the question were probably looking for (even though this is the most inefficient approach, since it linear searches through the list on every iteration):

```
def replace(l, X, Y):
  for v in l:
     i = l.index(v)
     if v == X:
        l.pop(i)
        l.insert(i, Y)

l = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
replace(l, 1, 7)
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach You're right. The method I was thinking of was `pop`.

Comment: @Serdalis The question disallows it (for whatever reason).

Comment: Sorry I misread that as "cannot use list constructors". You are correct.

Comment: @Asad. We're not allowed to use enumerate. Isn't it the same as in range(len(list))?

Comment: @StacyM: if you're not allowed `enumerate`, you can just use a manual index variable, and do `i += 1` at the end of the `for` block.

Comment: @Marius and Asad.   Ugh. Thank you. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this (not using `[]`s or `enumerate()`, as required):

```
for i in range(len(l)):  # loop over indices
    if l.__index__(i) == X:  # i.e. l[i] == X
        l.__setitem__(i, Y)  # i.e. l[i] = Y
```

This probably isn't what the assignment wants you to do, but I'll leave it here for learning purposes.

Note: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name since that's already used by a built-in function. I've used `l` here instead.

Answer (score 2):

If `enumerate` is not allowed, you can also use a `while` loop.

```
>>> def replace(L_in, old_v, new_v):
        while old_v in L_in:
            idx=L_in.index(old_v)
            L_in.pop(idx)
            L_in.insert(idx, new_v)


>>> L = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
>>> replace(L, 1, 7)
>>> L
[3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `list` as a name, it will cause you much pain.

```
def replace(my_list, X, Y):
    while X in my_list:
        my_list.insert(my_list.index(X), Y)
        my_list.pop(my_list.index(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Pretty straight forward. Probably a way of doing it with less lines, but based on what has been taught on the website so far, this works.

```
def replace(L, X, Y):
   while X in L:
      i = L.index(X)
      L.insert(i, Y)
      L.remove(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

totally agree with Asad Saeeduddin
but, 1st value of i must be -1, it will help replace the 1st object in list in need

```
def replace(l, X, Y):
    i = -1
    for v in l:
        i += 1
        if v == X:
            l.pop(i)  # remove item at given position (position number i)
            l.insert(i, Y)  # insert item Y at position i

l = [1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
replace(l, 1, 7)
print(l)
```